# How to efficiently throttle AJAX requests executed at a mouseover event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a table with dozens of rows (up to 100), and each row has 1 element with a mouseover event attached to it. On mouseover, I open a tooltip and need to make an AJAX request to fill it with some data.

My problem is fairly simple: if the user moves his mouse up and down over all the elements that have that event attached, I'm firing tons of requests at a time. I wanna throttle it one way or another, but I'm unsure how to.

I'm gonna have to check whether that same event has been executed in the last *n* seconds, but how do I keep a link between the firing of event 1 and firing of event 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a flag in the start of your AJAX call, if the flag is ZERO, return from the function. How you scope the varialbe is up to you.

```
if(AJAXOK==0) {
   return;
}    
AJAXOK = 1;
```

Set the variable in the AJAX call, so that is resets itself after a timeout:

```
window.setInterval(function() { AJAXOK = 1 },5000);
AJAXOK = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in trying a different approach, reactive extensions are designed for exactly this sort of thing:

http://reactive-extensions.github.com/RxJS